# Azure Toolkit for Intelli J error

Tags: azure, intellij-idea

I have installed Azure toolkit for Intelli J IDE on Windows 10 Azure VM and it is throwing the following error when I try to Sign in.

> Could not initialize class retrofit2.Platform
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   retrofit2.Platform    at
>   retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.(Retrofit.java:402)  at
>   com.microsoft.rest.RestClient$Builder.(RestClient.java:165)

I have used the same Intelli J IDE and plugin on Linux and it works fine. On the other hand I am able to sign in using the deprecated Azure HDInsightTools for Intelli J. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable "Android support" in the plugin setting panel?

[Disable Android Support in IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h84Cr.png)